# Maximum of the difference of values of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I have a vector:

```
A =
    0.5743
   -0.3167
    0.0591
   -0.2576
    0.0000
    0.2576
   -0.0591
    0.3167
   -0.5743
```

I want to store the differences between each value of the array A in an array or in a matrix, and find the maximum difference value, and output the indices (that is, v(1) - v(3) yields the maximum, for example) that yields the maximum. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
d = abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, A.')); %'// compute all differences
[~, ind] = max(d(:)); %// find linear index of maximum difference
[row, col] = ind2sub([numel(A) numel(A)], ind); %// convert to row and column
```

The sought indices are given by variables `row`,  `col`. The difference matrix is `d`.

Alternatively, the first line could be replaced by

```
d = squareform(pdist(A));
```

Comment: This is what I would have done too... especially `pdist` - +1.

Comment: @rayryeng But `bsxfun` is cool too... and `pdist` requires the Statistics Toolbox :-)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to MATLAB. I ran the code and received the error:Indexing cannot yield multiple results.

Comment: Define `A=[0.5743 -0.3167 0.0591 -0.2576 0.0000 0.2576 -0.0591 0.3167 -0.5743].';` and paste my code

Comment: Try `clear all` at the beginning. Also, try replacing second line by `[nada, ind] = max(d(:));`. What Matlab version do you have?

Comment: I have Matlab 2014b,mexw64. Unfortunately, the same error.

Comment: Okay, I restarted the program and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65783/discussion-between-user2147241-and-luis-mendo).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to compute all the differences.  You just need to find the maximum and minimum and subtract.

```
[max_val, max_ind] = max(A(:));
[min_val, min_ind] = min(A(:));
disp(['Max difference is ', num2str(max_val - min_val), ' which is the difference between indicies ', num2str(max_ind), ' and ', num2str(min_ind)]);
```

Comment: Can this be extended to find the minimum value? Also, how about the minimum of the difference squared? ((A(1) - A(2))^2, and so on). I think we need to find the largest two or smallest two and subtract them, and take the square root of it. Is there any other easier way to do it?